# Query Syntax LINQ works but Method Syntax LINQ gives runtime error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am using Entity Framework 7 RC1 Code First

I have a function that needs to returns a list of Countries(ids,Names) linked to a User.
The User isn't directly linked to the Country but is linked via the City. City is linked to State. State is linked to Country.

The following LINQ query syntax query returns me a list of unique countries sorted.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
{
    IQueryable<Country> table = from co in _db.Countries
                join st in _db.States on co.CountryId equals st.CountryId
                join ci in _db.Cities on ci.StateId equals st.StateId
                where (ci.UserId == userId)
                select co;
    return await table.Distinct().OrderBy(co => co.CountryName).ToListAsync();

}
```

However I need to write it in Linq method syntax

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
{
    IQueryable<Country> = _db.Cities
        .Include(ci => ci.State.Country)
        .Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
        .Select(ci => ci.States.Country)
        ;
    return await table.Distinct().ToListAsync();
}
```

This works but data is not sorted.

If I change it to be sorted

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
{
    IQueryable<Country> table = _db.Cities
        .Include(ci => ci.States.Country)
        .Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
        .Select(ci => ci.States.Country)
        ;
    return await table.Distinct().OrderBy(co => co.CountryName).ToListAsync();
}
```

gives me a runtime error of

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

If I move the orderby to just after the select

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
{
    IQueryable<Country> table = _db.Cities
        .Include(ci => ci.States.Country)
        .Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
        .Select(ci => ci.States.Country)
        .OrderBy(co => co.CountryName)
        ;
    return await table.Distinct().ToListAsync();
}
```

It works but doesn't return in sorted order

When I try to use a groupby

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Country>> Search(int userId)
{
    IQueryable<Country> table = _db.Cities
        .Include(ci => ci.States.Country)
        .Where(c => c.UserId == userId)
        .Select(ci => ci.States.Country)
        .GroupBy(ci => ci.States.Country)
        .Select(co => co.FirstOrDefault())
        .OrderBy(co => co.CountryName)
        ;
    return await table.ToListAsync();
}
```

I get the following runtime error

> InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Question: How do I write my query in LINQ method syntax?

Comment: Your first and second queries aren't the same at all - the first has two joins no includes and one ordering, the second has no joins but two includes and no ordering. It's fairly easy to convert your first query into method syntax, but is that actually what you want? And *why* do you need to use method syntax at all? If you've got code that works with query syntax, why not just keep that?

Comment: I was under the impression that  `Include(ci => ci.State.Country)`  is equivalent to `join st in _db.States on co.CountryId equals st.CountryId
                join ci in _db.Cities on ci.StateId equals st.StateId`  and neater seeing they are navigation properties on my model. Guess you're right. If it aint broke no need to fix it.

Comment: It may have the same effect under EF, but it's not what the compiler translates a join clause in a query expression into.

Comment: on your first syntax, this: `var IQueryable<Country> = _db.Cities` doesn't make any sense, it's either `var` or `IQueryable<Country>` and give it a name, like `var countries` or `IQueryable<Country> countries`.

Comment: That was simple typo. Fixed it.